# What is "py -m pip install XXX"

Tags: python, pip

`pip3 install [package]` works for me for installing the package but when I ran the file calling this package it said it can't find the package.

When I tried `py -m pip install [package]` it installed the package and the package is found by the file.

I'm curious about the function of `py -m`. Did I install the package in another place with the second command?

Comment: its the same as `python -m pip` by using it in this way it is easier to ensure that you are installing the package into the right python variant ... `python -m XXX` says to python to run the `__main__.py` that is found in the module (XXX) as a script

Comment: `py -m` is to run a module in the current dir such as [porcupine](https://github.com/Akuli/porcupine).